# How to resolve transitive dependency

Tags: database-design

In my project I have Job table that holds information for job posting. Every job can be targeted to *(this info is stored in JobLocations)*:

1. **only one country, be country wide**, *eg: (id = 1, idCountry = US, idRegion = null, idCity = null, idJob=3)*
2. **only one region, be region wide**, *eg: (id = 2, idCountry = US, idRegion = TX, idCity=null, idJob=5)*
3. **or more specific, can refer to multiple cities in the current country->region**

   *(id = 3, idCountry = US, idRegion = TX, idCity=78, idJob=7)*

   *(id = 4, idCountry = US, idRegion = TX, idCity=200, idJob=7)*

Some of the tables that I had created are these.
 [Job Locations http://imageshack.us/a/img267/5530/joblocations.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img267/5530/joblocations.png)
But I can see a problem with transitive dependency in table JobLocations, for example changing idCountry will lead to changing idRegion or idCity.

What other options do I have to remove the transitive dependencies and to achieve points 1, 2, 3 mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to have two "special" cities in each Region, one that means "anywhere in the region" and one that means "anywhere in the country".  The city code in `JobLocations` then serves to indicate the regionality (if you will) of the job.

To distinguish the special cities, you could encode them somehow (negative ids, for example) or, more correctly, add a type column to `City` that you look up through a join.

Once you have your special cities set up, you can drop the region and country FK columns from `JobLocations`.

BTW if I were you I'd drop the id columns from Country, Region, and City.  They're useless overhead, and invite error by allowing duplicate names.  `JobLocations` doesn't need an id either; it will have just JobID and City as columns, and its primary key includes both of them.

The rule *no job can be in two countries* is hard to enforce.  You'll need a trigger that says roughly `count(city) < 2 where type in ('country','region')`.  It's more complex than that, but the rules you describe can all be expressed as one `SELECT` statement.